# How to display data based on Selected dates in MVC4?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi   I want to return a list to view using json. I will explain my issue with example.
I have  2 fields FromDate ,ToDate and one button in my view. if i select the FromDate ,ToDate and click the button means it want to diaplay the data in the same view based  Date Selection

**Example Output**

[Example Op](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRw3Y.jpg)

[MyView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDZvu.jpg)

I want to bring the output same as like which is mentioned in the above Example output. That is if i select the From Date and To Date and Click the search button it  want to display the particular fields from( View_Visitorsform)based on From Date and ToDate selection. Particular Fields means some field i wish to display in view.

**My View Model**

```
public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
public string CustomerName { get; set; } 
public string POVisit { get; set; }
public string ContactPerson { get; set; } 
public Nullable<System.DateTime> NextAppointmnet { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
```

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult DailyVisitReport()
{
    return View();
}

public JsonResult GetDatesfromFromDateToDate(string fromdate, string Todate,VisitorsViewModel vvm)
{
    DateTime fromdt = Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate);
    DateTime todt = Convert.ToDateTime(Todate);
    List<View_VisitorsForm> VisitEntry = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm where v.VisitingDate <= fromdt && v.VisitingDate >=todt select v).ToList();
    return Json(VisitEntry,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here i got the From Date and To Date Value and list the data using query as per FromDate and ToDate Criteria . Now my issue i donno how to return  these list of data to view from Controller

**My View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToDate)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" }) 
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Ok" />
```

**My j query code**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#FromDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
        });
        $("#ToDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var cardetails = { fromdate: $("#FromDate").val(), Todate: $("#ToDate").val() };
            $.ajax(
                '@Url.Action("GetDatesfromFromDateToDate", "Report")', {
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(cardetails),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                success: function (data) {
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please any one tell me the solution to resolve this issue . I tried my level best to explain my issue .please any one understand and give me the solution..

Comment: What problem are you struggling with? How to convert your json response to build your table?

Comment: Stephen my issue is    i get the fromdate and todate using ajax                 DateTime fromdt = Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate);
    DateTime todt = Convert.ToDateTime(Todate);                                      and  also i list the data using                          List<View_VisitorsForm> VisitEntry = (from v in db.View_VisitorsForm where v.VisitingDate <= fromdt && v.VisitingDate >=todt select v).ToList();    Now  i want to display some of the fields from View_Visitors Form in the same view as per selected date criteria .how to do this task same as like which is mention in the above image

Comment: Firstly your parameters should be `DateTime fromdate, DateTime Todate` (they will be correctly bound - no need to the `Convert.ToDateTime()` code) and I recommend you just return a partial view of the table (or the `tbody` element), rather that json and then just update the DOM. You have not shown the relevant part of the view so impossible to give you the correct code - but something like `success: function (data) { $(yourTableElement).html(data); }`

Comment: ok wait stephen i will give the related part  by update my question

Comment: Stephen i have added another one view in that i have two fields from date and two date if i select the from date and to date and click the ok buttons means it need to display the data (which is mentioned in the below image)                                                                                       [List the data ][2]
 [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RCdFA.jpg      in the same view that is under From date and To date . I tried to explain my issue as per my level best . please understand my issue and give me solution

Comment: You need to edit your question to show the html for the table your want in the view

Comment: you understand my issue stephen

Comment: Yes, but your question needs to be clearer before I will add an answer (images are not acceptable)

Comment: how to give clear details stephen please tell me i donno how to give but i want solution it  urjent for me . help me

Comment: ok stephen im waiting for ur reply

Comment: stephen y u delete your answer??